# Automatically change button height in relative layout when there is no space

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have 2 ImageButtons and a ToggleButton in a relative layout that fills it's parent. Here is the xml code:

```
        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relative2">


        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_exposure_minus1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />


        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel_black"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />



        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="New ToggleButton"
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
            android:checked="false"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textOn="+"
            android:textOff="-"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

When the device is in portrait mode there is enough height room for the buttons. When the device is rotated to landscape, the relative layout gets smaller and there is no room for all the buttons. The lack of room is in the height dimension. So the Togglebutton that lays at the bottom of the other buttons is scaled automatically to smaller height, so that it fits.

I would prefer that all the buttons' height would be changed equally instead of just the last one (the ToggleButton) getting smaller in height. I would then have 3 buttons that have the same height, instead of 2 keeping the initial height and one with smaller height.
Could I get this result by changing the xml file?

PS: To make it more clear:

[image]

Comment: It may be better if you just create different layout for landscape mode. Relying on automatically resized button may cause button to be extremely hard to click if their size get too small.

Comment: you can use layout weight

Answer (score 0):

To make 3 buttons equal height, change your parent layout from relative layout to linear layout. And enable **layout weight** attribute equally. So they will be in same size.

Comment: If I used a linear layout then all button would be in one row (Vertical case) or in one column (Horizontal case). But I don't want them to be that way. The 2 Imagebuttons are one at the right of the other and the togllebutton below the 1st imagebutton.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **LinearLayout** if you want to make a uniform UI across different orientation.
Use **Orientation** property along with **layout weights** and you will get your desired result.

You just have to make nested Linearlayouts accordingly.

Here is your layout made using linear layout.

Hope you understand the significance of using linearlayouts.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_exposure_minus1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>


            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel_black"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="New ToggleButton"
                android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
                android:checked="false"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textOn="+"
                android:textOff="-"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```